# Automatic alternating labels in the description list

Tags: lists, labels, description

I need to use the description environment in such a way that I don't have to write alternating labels over and over again (as shown in the example below). Is there any way that these labels become automatic? It will save a lot of time and hassle. Thanks.

```
\begin{description}
\item[A:] text
\item[B:] text
\item[A:] text
\item[B:] text
\item[A:] text
\item[B:] text
\item[A:] text
\item[B:] text
\item[A:] text
\item[B:] text
\end{description}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! This looks like a dialog…

Comment: If you just have `\item[A: ]` and `\item[B: ]`, you can define new shortcuts for them: `\def\itema{\item[A: ]}` and `\def\itemb{\item[B: ]}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variant, based on the `enumerate` environment, with `enumitem` and `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlist{alternate}{enumerate}{1}
\renewcommand\labelalternatei{\bfseries\protect\ifnumodd{\value{alternatei}}{A:}{B:}}

\begin{document}

Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.
\begin{alternate}[wide=0pt]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Fourth
  \item Fifth
  \item Sixth
\end{alternate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With the help of package `enumitem` and some black magic which I am unable to explain.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\protected\def\mylabel#1{\ifodd#1A:\else B:\fi}
\AtBeginDocument{\sbox0{\bfseries A:\hspace\labelsep}%
                 %\edef\Ahmad{\dimexpr\number\wd0 sp\relax}% pleasing but slower
                 \edef\Ahmad{\the\wd0}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\mylabel{\value*},
                  itemindent=\dimexpr-\leftmargin+\Ahmad\relax, 
                  labelwidth=\Ahmad]
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{enumerate}

\begin{description}
\item[A:] text
\item[B:] text
\item[A:] text
\item[B:] text
\item[A:] text
\item[B:] text
\item[A:] text
\item[B:] text
\item[A:] text
\item[B:] text
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Why not `\dimexpr\the\wd0\relax` or simply `\the\wd0`? Also it should be `\sbox0{...}` instead of `\setbo0=\hbox{...}` and it should be done, together with the definition of `\Ahmad` in `\AtBeginDocument`, so LaTeX has already executed `\normalfont\normalsize`.

Comment: @egreg because I don't like points and prefer integers. I suspect it is faster with `sp` but I have often been proved wrong in my expectations regarding  `TeX` innards...

Comment: @egreg for `\AtBeginDocument` yes I wanted to do it, had started doing it, then I felt it would make too scary an approach. But will edit.

Comment: I tried to test with one million assignments `\dimen0=65536sp` and `\dimen0=1pt`. TeX was slower with sp by 27%

Comment: `65536` has five tokens. But in real life with `\the\wd0` there will also be more tokens in `\number`. Ok, I will test.

Comment: It's a bit slower also doing `\edef\test{\dimexpr\number\wd0\relax}` than `\edef\test{\the\wd0 }`. It's still faster doing `\dimen0=65.53pt` (with five tokens). In any case I don't think this has an impact on a real world document and with `\the\wd0` it's much clearer.

Comment: `10%` faster with `\the\wd0` viz `\number\wd0`. Slightly less if one adds the overhead of `\the\dimexpr` but still slower indeed. At least I sort of understand why: as I said `\number` produces more tokens than `\the`, plus `TeX` is fast from `decimal pt` to `sp`.

Comment: @egreg in my previous comment, read `20%` not  `10%` my test was biased by a typo.

Comment: @egreg just to add about `\number` producing more tokens: even worse with the added `sp`. e.g. `\number\dimexpr 65.536pt\relax --> 4294967` plus `sp` for `9` tokens compared to the `8` ah... not so much more. But with `\number\dimexpr 6.536pt\relax` which gives `428343` we thus have `6+2=8` compared to `7`. Not so much more either, but fits `10%`. Not `20%`. Anyhow, I said I am wrong at predicting the speed of `TeX` (except in some areas I have somewhat seriously tested; ah yes, I had forgotten that `\number` is slow).